# Kafka : Use case : Consumer is consuming only when producer is producer message

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, producer-consumer

Use case : Data range is very minimum and infrequent  between source and target . but still we need in real time . In that case, if I want onboard Kafka , is it possible to make consumer will start consuming the data only when producer is producing message . I knew producer and consumer are decoupled. But what is the best way to handle this use case with Kafka .

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Consumer is based on pull architecture. It polls the Kafka broker to fetch new messages (if any).

```
consumer will start consuming the data only when producer is producing message
```

If by this you mean - consumer process should come up only after data is produced, that is **not** provided out of the box in Kafka. You would need to implement logic to start kafka consumer when data is produced.

If it is okay for your consumer to be up all the time, it will continue polling the Kafka broker for new messages in predetermined intervals. Once the producer produces the data, the poll will return the messages that can be processed.

Comment: Thanks for your response Rishbah. Could you please share the reference page for this kind of use case would be great help. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want consumer to start only after producer has produced a message, kafka might not be the right choice. I am not aware of any on demand consumer with real time consuming. AWS batch might have worked in case some delay was acceptable.

Comment: Sure. What is specific reason  for "If you want consumer to start only after producer has produced a message, kafka might not be the right choice"

Comment: As explained in the answer, kafka consumer is pull based, so it has to keep asking (polling) kafka brokers to see if new message has come or not. There is no way to tell (push) to the consumer. For your use case, you want exactly the opposite. You want producer to tell the consumer to start processing.